# Проверка на числа даты в формате DDDD-DD-DD

Tags: c

Программа определяет день недели в заданную дату в формате `DDDD-DD-DD`.
Её проблема заключается в том, что она не проверяет, является ли числом знак `D`.

Ниже я указал, что я вводил и что программа считает за дату а что за слово :

```
 2015-09-01 [data]
 2015-08-aa [word]
 2012/08-26 [word]
 2015-08-_26 [word]
 2012/aa-26 [word]
 2012--8-26 [data??]
 2012=08-26 [word]
 2014-028-26 [word]
 2011-(8-26 [word]
 2011-(--26 [word]
 2011----26 [word]
 2311-(8-26 [word]
```

Все устраивает кроме одной строки : `2012--8-26`
Как это можно исправить используя только те библиотеки, которые подключены?

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf, scanf, sscanf
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> // time_t, struct tm, time, mktime

char buf[101];  // Max length


    int isDate (const char *buf) {

      if ( buf[4] == '-' && buf[7] == '-' && buf[10] == '\0' ) {
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        int year, month, day;

        if (sscanf(buf, "%u-%u-%u", &year, &month, &day) == 3) {

          time(&rawtime);
          timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
          timeinfo->tm_year = year - 1900;
          timeinfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
          timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
          mktime(timeinfo);

          return timeinfo->tm_wday;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }

int main (void) {

  int i = 0;
    const char * weekday[] = { "Sun", "Mon",
                             "Tue", "Wed",
                             "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};

        while(scanf("%100s", buf) != EOF)  // Scanning string until end of string.
        {
            if ((i = isDate(buf)) != -1)
            {
                printf ("date: %s %s", weekday[i], buf);
            }
            else // If not all of above - just word.
            {
                  printf ("word: %s",buf);
            }
            printf("\n");
        } // end of while
        return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: "вывод с проверкой" о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy изменил название, надеюсь устроит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом, ответ @Discord сработает, но можно проще. Поменяйте `%u` на `%d` и добавьте проверку на положительность полученных значений.
Ну и про `strlen` тоже хотел написать.

```
if (sscanf(buf, "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day) == 3 && year>0 && month>0 && day>0)
```

Проблема в том, что `-8` воспринимается как число (в отличие от `$8`, например). Собственно, тогда и проверку на разделители, вероятно, можно будет убрать.

Comment: Не подскажете, как правильно воспользоваться strlen в этом коде?

Comment: `if (strlen(buf) == 11)` вероятно, вместо `buf[10] == 0`

Comment: Почему `strlen(buf) == 11`? На самом деле 10. Но непосредственная проверка `buf[10]` лучше, т.к. быстрее (и даже безопасней).

Comment: @avp, еще раз, как сработает вызов `isDate("")`? В данном коде его нет, но это означает, что функция знает об окружающем коде. 10 возможно, я слишком редко пользуюсь c-строками.

Comment: @avp Так все же изменить проверку длины на strlen или оставить как есть?

Comment: @Danya я бы заменил `buf[10] == '\0'` на `strlen(buf) == 10` (именно 10, а не 11) Правда, это заголовок `cstring`. Или не передавал бы buf параметром в функцию, а оставил глобальной переменной. Тогда можно оставить как есть.

Comment: @Danya, откровенно говоря, что в лоб что по лбу. Я бы ограничился проверкой `sscanf(...) == 3 && year > 1900 && month > 0 && day > 0`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "%u-%u-%u"
> ```

```
"%u%*1[-]%u%*1[-]%u"
```

Впрочем, это лишь формат - сами числа-то не проверяются.

Comment: попробовал Ваш формат, не помогло.

Comment: @Danya, http://codepad.org/Bh6d9DXG - месяц получается `-8`. Это настолько же корректно, насколько 99, т. е. форматом не решается.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там unsigned формат, поэтому какой там получится месяц не вполне ясно, может и не -8.

Comment: @andy.37, `scanf` же одинаково обрабатывает `%d` и `%u`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не уверен: `d is for a signed argument, and u for an unsigned` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: @andy.37, по твоей ссылке: d or u Decimal integer Any number of decimal digits (0-9), optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).
d is for a signed argument, and u for an unsigned.
Т. е. описание общее, необязательны знак плюс или минус - для обоих.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да я читал. Но я не знаю, как точно работает `scanf`, а если с форматом `%u` она сначала засунет значение в unsigned переменную (временную) а потом обратно в signed month? В общем, я бы перестраховался.

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/rWfEMI

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int ishyphen(int ch) {
    return ch == '-';
}

int isdate(const char *s) {
    unsigned q;
    int (*f[])(int)= {
        isdigit, isdigit, isdigit, isdigit, ishyphen,
        isdigit, isdigit, ishyphen,
        isdigit, isdigit
    };

    for (q=0; q < sizeof f / sizeof *f; ++q)
        if (!f[q](s[q]))
            return 0;

    return !s[q];
}

int main(void) {
    char s[256];

    while(gets(s))
        printf("%s - %s\n", s, isdate(s) ? "yes" : "no");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но в вашем случае используется <ctype.h>, а нужен вариант только с теми тремя библиотеками

Comment: @Danya, `int isdigit(int ch) {
    return ch>='0' && ch<='9';
}` - и минус заголовочный файл. Кстати, он не библиотека.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вот это, хоть и сработает, думаю, всегда, но по-моему, стандартом не гарантируется, что коды цифр идут подряд.

Comment: @andy.37, и в какой же кодировке они не идут подряд?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да во всех идут, ясно. Но вот завтра я придумаю кодировку в которой не идут, и? П.С., с Вами интересно общаться, спасибо.